# Should I use car leather cleaner and conditioner products for sofa or other leather products?

Tags: furniture

There are many well known car leather cleaner and conditioner products for cars.

Should I use car leather cleaner and conditioner products for sofa or other leather products?
Could it cause long term issues?

Are the two furniture and car leather type are the same?

Comment: I think you need to read the labels on the products  you're interested in and check with the manufacturers.  That's all any of us would do.

Comment: product usage questions are off topic here

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thought. Are the type of car leather or furniture leather different?

Comment: @jsotola, I agree and that is why I am not mentioning any specific product brand. This is more of question like what type of glue ( hot glue vs epoxy) should I use for an application - but not asking for a brand.

Comment: are you asking people to guess what type of leather is used on some unknown furniture?

Comment: @jsotola, I don't know if that is something I need to look at. What are the type of leather used for furniture? Do we have different type of conditioner for all those types?

Comment: @jsotola, I have a typical Sofa bought from a furniture store. I bought it since I liked the look. I don't know much about leather type. That is why I am here. When I am searching internet, I am not finding people clean  leathers differently based on the type.

Comment: @jsotola, it seems that you are expert on this topic and you are genuinely trying to help. If I add a picture of my leather Sofa would it clarify, so I can get an answer?

Comment: the picture would be useless ... the manufacturer's cleaning instructions would be useful ... also the manufacturer's cleaning instructions for the automobile upholstery